# Can you use references for conditionalFormatting rules in R?

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, rules, openxlsx

I have a dataframe in R which is comprised of Weeks as the columns and categories in the rows.  The last four columns are summary statistics (include 52-week average and 52-week std deviation).  Each week a new column is added after the previous week and before the average-column.  I am using the conditionalFormatting function from openxlsx and I want the rule to be:  if week's data > (Average+Stdev) then color the cell red, if week's data<(Average-stdev) then color the cell green.
My problem is that I have to change the column names every week.  I am wondering if there is a way to have the rule use relative positions.

Here is a sample of the data:

| Code | Week1 | Week2 | Week3 | 52wk Avg | 52wk Stdev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 52304 | 10465 | 10812 | 12183 | 10522.1 | 2737.36 |
| 10000 | 6738 | 11125 | 1073 | 9382.98 | 4479.7 |

This is the code I'm using:

```
negStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", bgFill = "#FF0000")

posStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", bgFill = "#008000")

zeroStyle <- createStyle(fontColour ="#000000", bgFill = "#FFFFFF")

wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb,"Errors")

writeData(wb,"Errors",dfLocalErrors,rowNames=TRUE)

conditionalFormatting(wb, "Errors", cols = ((ncol(dfLocalErrors)-12):(ncol(dfLocalErrors)-3)), 
 rows=2:188,rule = "B2>($E2+$F2)",style = negStyle)
```

The code works, but next week I'll have to change the rule to `"C2>($F2+G2)"` as I need to keep the old data.

Any edits I make increase the risk of errors and if I want someone else to run the code they will have to remember to change it.

Is there a way to code the rule such that it doesn't have to be changed each week?

I tried:

```
(NCol(df)-5)>(($NCol(df)-2+$NCol(df)-1))`
```

but that doesn't work.
Thank you.

Comment: how will new data be added and ave/stdev adjusted each week? Would you be importing the previous week's openxlsx product and adding new week total in R?

Comment: I use the add_column function to add the new column and the average/stdev are recalculated using rowMeans and rowSds functions.  I hope that helps.  Thank you!